# Draw line across axis environments

Tags: pgfplots

I have placed a plot below another plot in pgfplots. The two plots reside in a separate `axis`environment each, like so:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.75]
  \begin{axis}[axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, scale
    only axis, name = main plot]
   \addplot[samples = 200] gnuplot{norm((x-2)/0.75)};
  \end{axis}

   \begin{axis}[at={(main plot.below south west)}, yshift=-0.3cm,
     anchor = north west, axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    axis lines = left, axis line style={->}, xmin = 0, xmax = 4, scale
    only axis, y = 6cm/3, ymin = 0, ymax = 1.0]
   \addplot[samples = 400] {gauss(2, 0.75^2)};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like to do is to draw vertical lines connecting points in the different `axis`environments, like so:

[image: Intended result]

Ideally I would be able to refer to coordinates inside the axis.